# My SSD is recognized as HDD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd

I have a problem where task manager reads SSD as HDD but previously task manager read my SSD correctly. I don't know what I did last time. Can anyone help me?

Screenshot taken from — 07/01/2021:
[image: 07/01/2021]

Screenshot taken from — 08/13/2021:
[image: 08/13/2021]

Comment: Run the following command within a elevated PowerShell prompt: *Winsat formal -restart -v* after the command finishes restart the machine

Comment: ok nice but not working :(